# Loading a JSON file inside AngularJS custom filter

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I'm new to Angular JS. I created a custom filter function and I have separate JSON files (which contain language translation data).

I'm storing the user's option in the local storage, and I want to load a specific JSON file's content into my custom filter based on that local storage value.

Ex: If the local storage value is equal to "french", then I need to load the French JSON file data. This is what I tried; Help me to continue this.

My custom filter looks like this:

```
app.filter("myFilter", function() {
    return function(input) {
        if(localStorageValue != null) {
            /*Load JSON file*/
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    };
});
```

The language translation JSON file looks like this (translate_fr.json)

```
{
    'SEARCH JOBS': 'Recherche de travail',
    'VIEW JOBS': 'Voir les offres',
    'Clean Up': 'Nettoyer',
    'Missed Bin' : 'Bin manqué',
    'Bin Replacement': 'Remplacement de bac',
    'Dumped Rubbish': 'Déchets déversés'
}
```

Comment: You can store json file name in local storage and pass it to the filter function

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. I'm getting the language name for the local storage and I need to retrieve data from seperate json files based on that..

Comment: can you provide more code / plunker demo of what you have tried ? As your question has ambiguity in requriements

Comment: At the moment I'm away from my pc and I'll update.Untill then I' explain it. There's a dropdown in the home page and user can select what language he/she wants to display the site. I'm storing that value into a local storage. I created seperate JSON files which includes translated data in different languages. (ex: translate_french.json, translate_spain.json). I created a custom filter(Its there) and in there I want to pass local storage value and retrive specific json file according to that value

Answer (score 0):

First inject the $http service

```
app.filter('filterName', ['$http', function(http){
return function(data){
}
 }]);
```

And use this to fetch JSON file

```
$http.get('translate_fr.json')
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.todos = res.data;                
    });
```